# What is Football game statistics Django Model logic?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating an app that visualizes football game statistics on Django. I take data from https://fbref.com/ as a CSV file. I have a python script that cleans data and create data frame with `['Player', 'Shots', 'SCA', 'Touches', 'Pass', 'Carries', 'Press', 'Tackled', 'Interceptions', 'Blocks']`   columns (I can add Team name, Game Date, Home/Away or whatever).
And now I need to create models to store this data. I don't know what models do I need.

Option 1 (only one model):

```
class GameStats(models.Model):
date = models.DateField()
team_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
home_away = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=HOME_AWAY)
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
number = models.IntegerField()
age = models.IntegerField()
shots = models.IntegerField()
SCA = models.IntegerField()
touches = models.IntegerField()
passes = models.IntegerField()
```

But it will give one Row of data. Technically, I can group rows by Team_name and Date.

Option 2:

```
from django.db import models


class Team(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  league = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Player(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  number = models.IntegerField()
  age = models.IntegerField()
  team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='team', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class HomeTeam(models.Model):
  team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='home_team', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  players = models.ManyToManyField(Player)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.team

class AwayTeam(models.Model):
  team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='away_team', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  players = models.ManyToManyField(Player)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.team

class Game(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  homeTeam = models.OneToOneField(HomeTeam, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  awayTeam = models.OneToOneField(AwayTeam, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

In Option 2 I can understand where to put Game statistics and a list of the players.

Would be great if someone could write proper models. I really stack!

Answer (score 1):

There is no one way to do it, so every answer you get for this question is going to be opinionated. That being said, for my personal preference, I would prefer the first modal approach as it is simple and has all the data in one place. I don't see a point of separating the columns into different database tables unless you know these different subset of columns are going to be used in some other models later down the line. Even then, you can always link the whole model with a ForeignKey to the new model and only use the data that you need.

Another reason I prefer the first approach is that the data does not have many columns, so dividing it into many smaller parts is making it complicated for no reason. You will be querying the database more in second approach, and later down the line, it may become difficult to keep track of things. But that is my opinion, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Decided to go with Option 1. For MVP better to use easy and fast choices. Thank you for your opinion!